# Error while starting NIFI after LDAP configuration

Tags: ldap, apache-nifi

I have successfully configured the NIFI to use HTTPS. But after this i am trying to configure LDAP authentication. I have modified the below files and while starting i am facing the exception as given below. Please help.

**nifi.properties**

```
nifi.security.user.login.identity.provider=ldap-provider
```

**login-identity-providers.xml**

```
<loginIdentityProvider>
    <provider>
        <identifier>ldap-provider</identifier>
        <class>org.apache.nifi.ldap.LdapProvider</class>
        <property name="Authentication Strategy">SIMPLE</property>
        <property name="Manager DN">cn=username,ou=xxx,ou=xxx,ou=Applications,dc=xxxxxx,dc=net</property>
        <property name="Manager Password">password</property>
        <property name="Referral Strategy">FOLLOW</property>
        <property name="Connect Timeout">10 secs</property>
        <property name="Read Timeout">10 secs</property>
        <property name="Url">ldap://hostname.net:636</property>
        <property name="User Search Base">dc=xxxxxx,dc=net</property>
        <property name="User Search Filter">(&(objectclass=inetOrgPerson)(groupMembership=cn=group,ou=xxx,ou=xxx,ou=groups,dc=xxxxxxx,dc=net))</property>
        <property name="Identity Strategy">USE_USERNAME</property>
        <property name="Authentication Expiration">12 hours</property>
    </provider>
```

**Errors:**

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'loginIdentityProvider': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.Exception: Unable to load the login identity provider configuration file at: /local/apache/nifi-1.11.4/./conf/login-identity-providers.xml
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:185)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:103)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1640)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:254)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1086)
        at org.apache.nifi.web.contextlistener.ApplicationStartupContextListener.contextInitialized(ApplicationStartupContextListener.java:93)
        ... 37 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Unable to load the login identity provider configuration file at: /local/apache/nifi-1.11.4/./conf/login-identity-providers.xml
        at org.apache.nifi.web.security.spring.LoginIdentityProviderFactoryBean.loadLoginIdentityProvidersConfiguration(LoginIdentityProviderFactoryBean.java:151)
        at org.apache.nifi.web.security.spring.LoginIdentityProviderFactoryBean.getObject(LoginIdentityProviderFactoryBean.java:108)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:178)
        ... 43 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely the **User Search Filter** you have provided. I would suggest trying with a simple filter which does not contain any special characters to narrow down the issue, then attempt to escape those characters if that is the case.

#### Response to additional information 2020-06-11

The complete `login-identity-providers.xml` file should look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<loginIdentityProviders>
    <provider>
        <identifier>ldap-provider</identifier>
        <class>org.apache.nifi.ldap.LdapProvider</class>
        <property name="Authentication Strategy">START_TLS</property>

        <property name="Manager DN"></property>
        <property name="Manager Password"></property>

        <property name="TLS - Keystore"></property>
        <property name="TLS - Keystore Password"></property>
        <property name="TLS - Keystore Type"></property>
        <property name="TLS - Truststore"></property>
        <property name="TLS - Truststore Password"></property>
        <property name="TLS - Truststore Type"></property>
        <property name="TLS - Client Auth"></property>
        <property name="TLS - Protocol"></property>
        <property name="TLS - Shutdown Gracefully"></property>

        <property name="Referral Strategy">FOLLOW</property>
        <property name="Connect Timeout">10 secs</property>
        <property name="Read Timeout">10 secs</property>

        <property name="Url"></property>
        <property name="User Search Base"></property>
        <property name="User Search Filter"></property>

        <property name="Authentication Expiration">12 hours</property>
    </provider>
</loginIdentityProviders>
```

Comment: i tried with below but i am facing same issue.

<property name="User Search Filter">cn={0}</property>

<property name="User Search Filter">(cn={0})</property>

Comment: I assumed it was just a copy/paste issue, but the `login-identity-providers.xml` file you posted above is missing the closing `</loginIdentityProvider>` element (and the surrounding XML elements). Can you post the full file, and if that is what you posted above, reference the template file which is provided to see the complete XML content.

Comment: hi Andy, NIFI was successfully started after i resolving the tag name. i changed it to loginIdentityProviders. s was missing in my xml file.

<loginIdentityProviders>
</loginIdentityProviders>

And now i am able to see the login page. i am unable to login with any user. can you please suggest if i need to modify the authorizers.xml file also? if i have the client certificate in my browser i am able to load page with login page.